# Precision and Recall in Clustering (Application in Spark, Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Trying to solve the problem of measuring model evaluation statistics (precision and recall) from clustering algorithms in Spark. [Original inspiration from cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15158/precision-and-recall-for-clustering) for pairwise overlap-based cluster evaluation underminer's response.

Creating this sample test data, I am able to get the total predicted positives.

How would you go about computing the true positives?  In particular, the transformation of the spark data frame to get the result. Many thanks for any inspiration.

```
+-----+----------+
|label| cluster  |
+-----+----------+
|    x|         1|
|    x|         1|
|    x|         1|
|    x|         1|
|    x|         1|
|    x|         2|
|    x|         3|
|    x|         3|
|    o|         1|
|    o|         2|
|    o|         2|
|    o|         2|
|    o|         2|
|    d|         2|
|    d|         3|
|    d|         3|
|    d|         3|
+-----+----------+
```

```scala
// the nCk function to be used as a UDF
def choose(n: Int, k: Int): Int ={ 
  if (k==0) 1 else (n * choose(n-1, k-1)) / k 
}

val udf_choose = udf(choose _)

// the combined sum of true positive and false positive
val tp_fp = (df.groupBy("cluster")
               .count()
               .filter($"count" > 1)
               .withColumn("combinations", udf_choose($"count", lit(2)))
               .agg(sum("combinations"))
               .first().getLong(0))

// How to calculate True Positive?
```

OUTPUT

```
tp_fp: Long = 40
```

Answer (score 1):

Metrics used for classification are meaningless for clustering algorithms. When applying standard clustering techniques there is no "true" answer, and results can highly affected by:

- Initialization process.
- Exact content of the training dataset (in some cases adding or removing a single object can significantly affect the final result).

At the same time clustering algorithms don't use labels in their cost function.

Finally assigned labels don't carry any special meaning. You can permute labels without affecting overall cost.

If clustering is based on Euclidean distance the reasonable choice of the measure of the quality is inter-cluster, intra-cluster variance.